# no me funciona text-lg-light bootstrap

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap

hola estoy intentando cambiar el color de un texto en funcion del tamaño de la pantalla:

```
echo("<a href='listadoPedidos.php' class='text-lg-light'>Pedidos pendientes: ".$fila['nPedidos']."</a>");
```

pero por alguna razon no esta funcionando, es como si no pusiese nada en la clase. ¿sabeis por que?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que no existen clases en Bootstrap para cambiar el color del texto de acorde al tamaño del dispositivo. Solamente existen: text-light, text-success, etc.

Podrías intentar con CSS, con las siguientes líneas:

```
.text-color {
    color: black;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
    .text-color {
        color: white !important;
    }
}

`echo "<a href='listadoPedidos.php' class='text-color'>Pedidos pendientes: ".$fila['nPedidos']."</a>";`
```

Estas líneas hacen que el texto sea color negro en dispositivos grandes (PC, Laptop, tabletas), y que en dispositivos móviles el color del texto sea blanco. Tú puedes jugar con los tamaños y colores según tus necesidades.

EDIT: te recomiendo retirar los paréntesis del echo.

Comment: perfecto, me funciono.

Answer (score 0):

`text-lg-light` no existe en el repo de bootstrap, `text-lg` se aplica según la documentación [getbootstrap - text](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/text/), y el estilo `btn btn-light` [doc de estilos de botones](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/buttons/)